# Display results one per line in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to display the results of a rails c query with each result placed on a separate line, rather than just all in-line?

As example of what I mean take the normal mac terminal list files command. Take the difference between:

```
$ ls
CNAME               README.md           _layouts            config.rb           index.html          package.json            stylesheets
Gemfile             _config.yml         _posts              contact.html            js              rss.xml
Gemfile.lock            _drafts             _site               copyright.html          scss
Gruntfile.js            _includes           assets              node_modules            sitemap.xml
```

and

ls -l
total 120

```
-rw-r--r--   1 Luke  staff   140 12 Mar 22:45 Gemfile
-rw-r--r--   1 Luke  staff   637 12 Mar 22:45 Gemfile.lock
-rw-r--r--   1 Luke  staff  2312 12 Mar 22:45 Gruntfile.js
-rw-r--r--   1 Luke  staff   996  4 Jan  2014 README.md
-rw-r--r--   1 Luke  staff   317  4 Jan  2014 _config.yml
drwxr-xr-x   7 Luke  staff   238 17 Feb 09:56 _drafts
drwxr-xr-x  15 Luke  staff   510 14 Jul 18:28 _includes
drwxr-xr-x   6 Luke  staff   204  6 Apr 19:32 _layouts
drwxr-xr-x   9 Luke  staff   306 14 Jul 18:29 _posts
drwxr-xr-x  18 Luke  staff   612 14 Jul 18:29 _site
drwxr-xr-x  11 Luke  staff   374  4 Jan  2014 assets
-rw-r--r--   1 Luke  staff   930 12 Mar 22:45 config.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 Luke  staff   725  6 Apr 19:34 contact.html
-rw-r--r--   1 Luke  staff  1819  6 Apr 19:34 copyright.html
-rw-r--r--   1 Luke  staff  1892 12 Mar 22:45 index.html
drwxr-xr-x   7 Luke  staff   238 12 Mar 22:45 js
drwxr-xr-x  16 Luke  staff   544  6 Jan  2014 node_modules
-rw-r--r--   1 Luke  staff   536 12 Mar 22:45 package.json
-rw-r--r--   1 Luke  staff   891  4 Jan  2014 rss.xml
drwxr-xr-x  26 Luke  staff   884  6 Apr 19:34 scss
-rw-r--r--   1 Luke  staff  1717  4 Jan  2014 sitemap.xml
drwxr-xr-x   5 Luke  staff   170  6 Apr 19:34 stylesheets
```

Comment: exactly what "query" do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit : I try to be more explicit.

You can try pry instead of irb console, pry is an alternative ruby shell with a lot of features ( have a look here for more details : http://pryrepl.org/ ). One of them features is to format results output. With this a collection appears with one item by line.

Example : without pry

```
2.1.1 :001 > User.all
  User Load (7.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, first_name: "Foo", last_name: "Bar", created_at: "2014-07-24 14:33:34", updated_at: "2014-07-24 14:33:34">, #<User id: 2, first_name: "Bar", last_name: "Foo", created_at: "2014-07-24 14:33:34", updated_at: "2014-07-24 14:33:34">, #<User id: 3, first_name: "Bar", last_name: "Bar", created_at: "2014-07-24 14:35:34", updated_at: "2014-07-24 14:35:34">]>
```

with pry :

```
[1] pry(main)> User.all
  User Load (4.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
=> [#<User id: 1, first_name: "Foo", last_name: "Bar", created_at: "2014-07-24 14:33:34", updated_at: "2014-07-24 14:33:34">,
 #<User id: 2, first_name: "Bar", last_name: "Foo", created_at: "2014-07-24 14:33:34", updated_at: "2014-07-24 14:33:34">
 #<User id: 3, first_name: "Bar", last_name: "Bar", created_at: "2014-07-24 14:35:34", updated_at: "2014-07-24 14:35:34">]>
[2] pry(main)>
```

You can install it easily : add [pry-rails](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) into you Gemfile

```
gem 'pry-rails', :group => :development
```

and make `bundle install`

launch a console

```
rails console
```

Hope this helps

Comment: please explain how this help?